# How to convert degrees minutes seconds to hour minutes seconds (and viceversa)?

Tags: angle

I'm reading the book "[Practical Astronomy with your Calculator or Spreadsheet 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108436072)" and I want to implement formula **22: Converting between angles expressed in degrees and angles expressed in hours**. It says that:

> To convert between angles expressed in decimal hours and angles
>   expressed in decimal degrees, simply multiply or divide by 15.

So, I have to convert a angle in degrees minutes and seconds into decimal degrees and then multiply it 15 (or divide it by 15?).

When do I have to multiply and when do I have to divide by 15?

Or

How to convert degrees minutes seconds to hour minutes seconds (and viceversa)?

Comment: Hint: The angle in degrees in the range $[0^\circ, 360^\circ)$ converts to the angle in hours in the range $[0, 24)$; note that $360=15\times 24$ so that is where the factor $15$ comes from.

Comment: So, to get degrees I have to multiply hours, and to get hours I have to divide it by 15. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Nope!  360 degrees is 24 hours.  360 divided by 24 is 15.  So 15 degrees is 1 hour of right ascension.

Answer (score 0):

In one day = $24$ hours the sky ''rounds'' $360°$, so:
$$
24:360=h:\alpha°
$$

Answer (score 0):

Each hour is $360^\circ/24=15^\circ$. Each minute of time is $15^\circ/60=15^\prime$, i.e. $15$ arcminutes. Each second of time is $15^\prime/60=15^{\prime\prime}$, i.e. $15$ arcseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Most clocks feature a $12$ hours dial and a full turn is $360°$. Hence an hour is $30°$ !